# R Highchart // grouped categories in x axis

Tags: r, highcharts

I want to create a stacked bar chart with grouped categories like [there](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories).

This is my example dataframe:

```
region <- c("bavaria", "bavaria", "bavaria", "bavaria", "berlin", "berlin", "berlin", "berlin")
year <- c(2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017)
month <- c(11, 12, 01, 02, 11, 12, 01, 02)
sales <- c(20, 17, 10, 5, 18, 16, 10, 7)
inc_sales <- c(3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2, 0)
df <- data.frame(region, year, month, sales, inc_sales)
```

The x axis should be grouped by month / year / region, where month is on top.

I already coded this with only using month as x axis:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(highcharter)

highchart() %>% 
      hc_chart(type = "column") %>% 
      hc_title(text = "Sales") %>% 
      hc_xAxis(categories = df$month) %>%
      hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Sales")) %>% 
      hc_plotOptions(column = list(
        dataLabels = list(enabled = FALSE),
        stacking = "normal",
        enableMouseTracking = TRUE)
      ) %>% 
      hc_series(list(name="sales",data=df$inc_sales),
                list(name="inc_sales",data=df$sales))
```

Can someone help me to group the categories?

Comment: Have you and image of what you want, or similar?

Comment: Hi @jbkunst. This (http://i.stack.imgur.com/icqbN.png) is similiar to what I want in Excel. You can see what I mean with grouping of the x axis categories. (It is not the same data, but a good example for the x axis!)

Comment: Mmm, not that simple but possible ;)! You need to add manually (by now) the grouped categories plugin (http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories) then use this example https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/172#issuecomment-249262645 to get http://rpubs.com/jbkunst/highcharter-issue-172. If I have time I could try to do the same as the demo data

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(region, date=paste(month, year, sep="-"), sales, inc_sales)
df

highchart() %>% 
hc_chart(type = "column") %>% 
hc_title(text = "Some Title") %>%
hc_add_series(name="Sales",data = df$sales  ) %>% 
hc_add_series(name="Inc Sales", data = df$inc_sales) %>%
hc_xAxis(categories = list(
list(
  name =  "Bavaria",
  categories = list("11-2016","12-2016","1-2017","2-2017") 
      ),
list(
  name =  "Berlin",
  categories = list("11-2016","12-2016","1-2017","2-2017") 

)
) )%>%

hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "percent"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the 'Grouped Categories' option helpful:
[highcharter examples](http://jkunst.com/highcharter/plugins.html#grouped-categories)